# Error while Adding Poster Image to an Audio File in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

i have installed ffmpeg in ubuntu and tried to do the following:
when i tried to add an image(color2.jpg) to an audio file (sample.mp3) i got an error saying 
"Unable to find a suitable output format for 'experimental'
experimental: Invalid argument"

Comment: This is the command i tried:

Comment: ffmpeg -loop 1 -i color2.jpg -i sample.mp3 -c:v libx264 -c:a –strict experimental -b:a 192k -shortest outputfile.mp4

Answer (score 0):

If you just wish to include a video stream with your audio, then use the current command with one correction, specify the name of the audio codec :

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i color2.jpg -i sample.mp3 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k -shortest outputfile.mp4
```

(If you're using a FFmpeg version from Dec 2015 or later, you don't need `-strict experimental`)